# how i can say, if label.text == any Int

Tags: string, swift, if-statement, int, label

How can i say: if label.text == any Int

```
  if label.text == (Any, Int) {
            label1.text = "Might be another Integer"
        }
```

If you have enough time to answer one more question that would be great:
How can i say: if label.text == any Int except 42

please separate the question, and thank you for the help

Comment: Do you mean, if `label.text` is an `Int`? Because `label.text == (Any, Int)` suggests something totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
class Label {
    var text: String? = "43"
}

let label = Label()

if let text = label.text, let int = Int(text) where int != 42 {
    print("I'm \(int), not 42!")
}

// prints: I'm 43, not 42!
```

If this looks a bit messy, you can wrap it like so:

```
if
    let text = label.text,
    let int = Int(text)
    where int != 42
{
    print("I'm \(int), not 42!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, your question is not clear but i will try to anwer, the property `.text` of a `label` will always be an object of type String, so it will never be an Int, but by reading your second question i assume that you want to check if is an Integer number and not an object Int, so you can create a function to check if a String contains a number:

```
function checkIfAStringIsANumber(str:String)->Bool{
        let decimalCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
        let decimalRange = str.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(decimalCharacters)

        if decimalRange != nil {
            return true;
        }
return false;
}
```

And use it in this way:

```
if (checkIfAStringIsANumber(label.text)) {
    label1.text = "Label contains an integer value!"
}
```

**Second question:**
To avoid some numbers you can modify the function we created before to do something like this:

```
    function checkIfAStringIsANumberWithoutSomeValues(str:String,excludedValues:[Int])->Bool{
let decimalCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
let decimalRange = str.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(decimalCharacters)

                if decimalRange != nil {
                   let intObj = Int(str);
                      if excludedValues.contains(intObj) {
                         return false;
                      }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
        }
```

And you can use it like this:

```
let excludedValues:[Int] = [42,31,89,101] //Values that you want to exclude, if you want to exclude only 42 simply write [42]
if(checkIfAStringIsANumberWithoutSomeValues(label.text,excludedValues){
label1.text = "integer found"
}
```